# PRISM 4 WPF LoggedIn user

Tags: wpf, prism, unity-container

I am trying to create an application following, modular architecture, using Prism 4 & UnityContainer for DI. I am wondering how you would pass the currently logged in user around the system?

I thought nice and dirty would be to validate my user login credetials with a simple login form, hit my dataContext(EntityFramework 4) on application startup and store in applications' App.Xaml.cs using:

```
App.Current.Properties["CurrentUser"] = user;
```

But obviously my loaded modules do not have any knowledge of the application. Stuck...

Thanks if you can offer any help.

Answer (score 0):

Got what appears to be a "proper" solution from the chaps over at CodePlex Prism discussions here http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/429579